# Delete multiple revisions at one time

Tags: 7

Most articles of my site contain huge revisions. It is very tedious and annoying to delete huge revisions one by one following the url ,say, www.example.com/node/9022/revisions. I want to implement an interface in Admin panel to delete multiple revisions at one time. But dont know how to implement this concept. Plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the most relevant module [node_revision_bulk_delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_revision_bulk_delete) for the implementing my task and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Node Revision Delete](http://drupal.org/project/node_revision_delete) module to delete and manage your revisions.

> The Node Revision Delete module lets you to track and prune old revisions of content types.